# astlib coordinates code to astropy coordinates code

Tags: python, coordinates, coords, astropy

I'm trying to fix this code which used `astlib` to convert coordinates to use the `astropy` coordinate modules. Here's a copy of the code:

```
from astLib import astCoords as coords

#Convert B1950 coordinates (as given)
clra=zeros(3)
cldec=zeros(3)
for i in range(len(clra)):
    clra[i], cldec[i] = coords.convertCoords(
                                'B1950', 'J2000', clra1950[i],
                                cldec1950[i], 1950
                            )

#Convert input coords to Galactic coords
lgal,bgal = radians(coords.convertCoords(
                        'J2000', 'GALACTIC', ra, 
                        dec,2000
                    ))
```

I need help with 2 things.

1. What are the proper imports for `astropy` if I want to change from `B1950` to `J2000`, and the proper imports to go from `J2000` to galactic coordinates?
2. in the areas that start with `coords.convertCoords()`, What are the functions and arguments from astropy that go in its place. In other words, what do I replace it with?

Also, I had done some research into this issue. I found this link here: http://docs.astropy.org/en/v0.2.1/coordinates/

It describes the notation for `astropy's` coordinate related functions. However, there is a lot there, and I'm not sure what to use and how to use it.

Comment: FWIW those Astropy docs are pretty old.  You can always get the docs for the latest release here: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/index.html  (see also the Readthedocs version selection menu in the bottom right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from astropy import units as u

In [3]: from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, FK4, FK5, Galactic

In [4]: clra = np.zeros(3)

In [5]: cldec = np.zeros(3)

In [6]: c1 = SkyCoord(clra * u.deg, cldec * u.deg, frame=FK4)

In [7]: c2 = c1.transform_to(FK5(equinox='J2000'))

In [8]: c3 = c2.transform_to(Galactic)

In [9]: print(c3.l.degree)
[ 97.74220094  97.74220094  97.74220094]

In [10]: print(c3.b.degree)
[-60.18102359 -60.18102359 -60.18102359]
```

Note that you can convert `c1` to Galactic directly too.